# 12.Ubuntu server credentials for Raspberry Pi

Tags: login, 20.04

The documents I've seen say that ubuntu/ubuntu should work, but I am not able to get them to work. I've seen the suggestion that it may take a few tries before it works, but I have tried many times and nothing I can think of works. I'd appreciate any suggestion. This is version 20.04 (32-bit) on a Raspberry Pi 3 B, but I don't know why the hardware would make a difference. The default credentials on other distributions (pi/raspberry) don't work either. I must say that I don't have any experience with Ubuntu. I started with SCO Unix and AIX until SCO went out of business and I've been using OpenBSD ever since. So my ability to help someone else is limited, but would still appreciate any help. I will try downloading another version if nobody knows what the answer is.

Comment: Yes, it's ubuntu/ubuntu. Your keyboard works properly? Is this a local login or via ssh?

Comment: I tried three keyboards, all working on other computers, and they all behave the same. The user name is displayed properly, so I have to assume that the password is being sent properly as well. Unfortunately I don't think it's a hardware problem, but that this particular image had a different password.It's a local connection. I was going to try ssh, but it also seems to have a fixed IPv6 address that I can't get to. The dhcp server still shows the device's IP address from last night, when it was running a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Pi 4 version an installed it on a Pi 4B and it worked fine. I believe the original problem was that it was installed on an mSATA drive rather than an SD card.